# Python script runs without error but fails to print output to file or screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have been a java developer for long and this is my first encounter with python. I found a jumbled up python code and worked on it to make it readable and executable. I have achieved both, but I do not get output for the program. Can someone help me understand if it is a syntactical or logical error that is causing this?

This code is a program that executes the knapsack problem for a given situation. The input is read from a file, and all the parameters like value and weight, which are separated by ":" are parsed by the initial lines. Thereafter, it is stored into a list to determine how much of each item should go in before max value is reached

```py
with open("inputPS1.txt") as f:
    line = f.readline().strip().split(":")
    n = int(line[1].strip())
    line = f.readline().strip().split(":")
    wt = int(line[1].strip())
    lst = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split("/")
        lst.append([line[0], int(line[1].strip()), int(line[2].strip())])
        #print(lst)
        lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

cals = 0
for itm in lst:
    if wt == 0:
        itm.append(0)
    continue
    if itm[1] <= wt:
        wt -= itm[1]
        itm.append(itm[1])
        cals += itm[2] * itm[1]
    else:
        itm.append(wt)
        cals += itm[2] * wt
        wt = 0
        lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
        print("Total calories: " + str(cals) + "\n")
        print("Food Item selection Ratio:\n")
    for itm in lst:
        print(itm[0] + ": " + str(itm[3]) + "\n")
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Summary:

1. Found the code for some task, but it was unreadable. Wrote it again and made it run
2. Fixed indentations wherever needed

Expectations:

1. Wanted to print the output to file, but the program didnt.
2. So tried to print on screen. Still no output
3. using an IDE to compile and run`

Comment: This code is a program that executes the knapsack problem for a given situation. The input is read from a file, and all the parameters like value and weight, which are separated by ":" are parsed by the initial lines. Thereafter, it is stored into a list to determine how much of each item should go in before max value is reached

Comment: Add this to your question it will be easier for other people..

Comment: The `continue` 3 lines into your for loop is going to skip any printing

Comment: As Elijah said above, the `continue` statement there. Seems you missed an indentation level there. It should be indented relative to the `if wt == 0:` statement.

Comment: @Exampleperson you are correct, but with a proper Python IDE such as **PyCharm**, one can immediately see where one messed up: All the lines after `continue` will be "faded away" indicating that they will never get executed, thus (hopefully) bringing one's attention to a misplacement of the `continue` statement

Comment: @pepoluan  i tried indenting continue but still no output...can i request a little more help here? thanks

Comment: It would be better if you give us input and desired output and your thoughts about how to make first into second, and we would be glad to help you. Can you please show us how "inputPS1.txt" data looks like and what you want to make it into?

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva the input file is like this   Food Items: 6
  Maximum Bag Weight: 10 
  F1 / 5 / 22 
  F2 / 3 / 50
  F3 / 8 / 18
  F4 / 2 / 60
  F5 / 1 / 35
  F6 / 2 / 22

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva output should be Total calories: 393 Food Item selection Ratio: F1 : 4 F2 : 3 F3 : 0 F4 : 2 F5 : 1 F6 : 0

Comment: what logic creates this numbers: `F1 : 4 F2 : 3 F3 : 0 F4 : 2 F5 : 1 F6 : 0` and `Total calories: 393`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your support. The problem was pretty simple, really. As pointed out, it was the "continue" statement that caused the issue.

[corrected syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDNnZ.png)

Apart from that, the code also has a small error that can lead to array index out of bound exception.

Porting the code to pycharm helped. Here is the output:

```
**/usr/bin/python3.10 /media/aakash19/31C6-98C2/softwares/assignment/assignment.py
```

F4 : 60
F2 : 50
F5 : 35
F1 : 22
F6 : 22
F3 : 18
F4 : 60
F2 : 50
F5 : 35
F1 : 22
F6 : 22
F3 : 18
F4 : 60
F2 : 50
F5 : 35
F1 : 22
F6 : 22
F3 : 18
Total calories: 393
Food Item selection Ratio:
F1 : 22
F2 : 50
F3 : 18
F4 : 60
F5 : 35
F6 : 22**

Thanks a lot once again. I hope to come back with some more interesting issues.